# How can I get the list of all my issues across all projects at code.google.com?

Tags: google-code

How can I see all the issues I reported at https://code.google.com/, **across all projects**?

Note that there is a similar question (or change request) on starred issues from 2006 but still unresolved: https://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=38

There is an advanced search form that allows to search the "reporter" field, but only within a specific project.

Comment: To put it another way, it sounds like you're looking for a Google Code feature similar to GitHub's [Issues Dashboard](https://github.com/blog/941-issues-dashboard).